# NextJS application with Docker failing to deploy after upgrading from version 13.4.13 to version 13.4.15

Tags: docker, next.js, google-cloud-run

My NextJS application is successfully building the container image, but after upgrading from version `13.4.13` to version `13.4.19`, Cloud Run would eventually give this error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update) Revision 'devrel-demos-00085-yaf' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.`

By incrementally upgrading through each patch version, I know that `13.4.13` deploys successfully and `13.4.15` does not. For those using Docker, I believe this is a breaking change in version [13.4.15](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v13.4.15) that is possibly related to the changes made to [Better IPv6 support for `next-server`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/53131).

How can I get my Cloud Run deployments to start working again with the latest version of NextJS?

Answer (score 2):

Due to recent changes, you now need to add this line to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"
```

There has been a [pull request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/54342) that fixed the issue in the docs for new projects using the [with-docker](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker) example. Projects already using Docker and NextJS will need to add that line.

The full, [working Dockerfile example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile) now includes that as the second-to-last line. This is the current snapshot of that example:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: Luke, do you have a link to the recent change that introduced this problem?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but if I had to guess, I think it's related to the change on this line of the pull request: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/53131/files#diff-3a7de5f9ca3729cdc0a041e9d4c22391754e702ba49ba230daf55730bdc70d99R1975

Comment: Yes, that change would cause the problem in Cloud Run.

Comment: 4 hours of my life gone over this :,(